# how to write text right to left (Arabic Text)in Android ?

Tags: android, text, right-to-left

I used Arabic text so,
I want to write text from right to left so how i can write right to left text in android ?

Regards,
Girish

Comment: please would you tell me how can you write arabic on android emulator ?

Answer (score 10):

Try with [Bidi](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare in your app manifest that your app supports RTL mirroring: add *android:supportsRtl="true"* to the  element in your **manifest** file.
2. Change all of your app's "left/right" layout properties to new "start/end" equivalents.

[Native RTL support in Android 4.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is only possible starting with [jelly bean](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html)

Comment: More specifically Android 4.2. RTL support in 4.1 is quite limited. See [this blog entry](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) for details.

Comment: the BidiFormatter APIs are also now available for earlier platform versions through the Support Package in the Android SDK.

Answer (score -1):

use this

**android:textDirection="rtl"**

**android:gravity="right"**

Comment: While this does provide an answer to the question, you don't explain what it does, why it does it, or really anything for that matter. Especially because this question is more than 3 years old, it would be good to have a more complete, up-to-date answer for newer versions of Android.