# right to left tex in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, persian

I am trying to display Persian text on android(load Persian font also) and it showed successively but it is left to right instead of right to left for example :
سلام would be displayed as م ا ل س (i use ndk and cocos2d-x)

Comment: Check out this post. It doesn't have an accepted answer but one of the two possible solutions may be correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874125/how-to-write-text-right-to-left-arabic-textin-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set layout.directions to ALIGN_OPPOSITE

Comment: how should i do this in view!?