# How to write text in Hebrew on the button

Tags: android, button, layout, right-to-left, hebrew

This is my button in main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/checkInButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/checkIn"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Are there any property in order to make it RTL, in other words from right to left?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874125/how-to-write-text-right-to-left-arabic-textin-android 
Check this if helps

Comment: What's the lowest version of Android that you want this to work on? The answer varies.

Comment: Usually you will simply see it work OK when you use the string resource in utf-8. Is there some specific problem in your app? Which version of Android do you run?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Android Developers](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) have a few directives that might help you with this.

- [android:layoutDirection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3alayoutDirection) — attribute for setting the direction of
  a component's layout.
- [android:textDirection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atextDirection) — attribute for setting the direction of a
  component's text.
- [android:textAlignment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atextAlignment) — attribute for setting the alignment of a
  component's text.
- [getLayoutDirectionFromLocale()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#getLayoutDirectionFromLocale%28java.util.Locale%29) — method for getting the
  Locale-specified direction.