# How set my ACTION BAR to support right to left

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.2-jelly-bean, right-to-left

I am very new on android and want to write an application that support rtl languages. for that I wrote

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

on application part of manifest file and call forceRightToLeft on oncreate method of android. The method have following body:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void forceRTLIfSupported() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(
                View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
}
```

but I understand on sdk API 16(Android 4.1) and the version before that didn't supported and action bar show left to right. I search but couldn't find any solution. 
Please don't minus my code just let me to know and then I will delete it if it is not true question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Bidi class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html)

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874125/how-to-write-text-right-to-left-arabic-textin-android) also.

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question, I read bindi but this class is for text, isn't it? My problem is about actionbar. I can't have actionbar format in all the APIs.

Comment: Yes it i about texts.
I am sorry, I don't have any idea about how to fix the action-bar ... you should may be ask your question more clearer : "How set my ACTION BAR to support right to left ?" and not "my app" .
good luck :)