# Arabic language words wrong displaying: left to right

Tags: android, arabic

i'm trying to display an arabic text (Right to Left) in my app, but i get words displayed left to right in lines.

I'm using an arabic supporting font and arabic reshaper lib. The text is loaded from strings file.

The app support Android 2.1.

Here a screen shot for the result:

[image: Arabic Text wrong display]

For more details:

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView tvtest = null;
private static Typeface typeface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvtest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtest);
    tvtest.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshape(getString(R.string.first_part)));
    Typeface tf;
    tf = GetFont(getApplicationContext());
    tvtest.setTypeface(tf);
}

public static final Typeface GetFont(Context context) {
    if (typeface == null) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                // "DroidSansFallback.ttf");
                "MSHQW.TTF");
    }
    return typeface;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7874409/4224337 ?

Comment: android 2.1 does not support arabic.

Comment: @njzk2 If you use ArabicReshaper it works but with problems in words order.

Comment: I have used ArabicReshaper a couple of years ago, but I don't remember anything about word order issue. can you post the code where you are reshaping the text?

Comment: @Rami could you give me more details how to use Bidi please?

Comment: @Mohammad Abu Hmead could you please help i saw you had a similar problem before

Comment: @Med_mofid I know its old issue but did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set gravity of your `TextView`.

in code:

- `textView.setGravity(...);

or in XML:

- `android:gravity="..."`

Comment: The problem is with words display order not text gravity.

Comment: In what direction do you get the text? 5-4-3-2-1?